# How can I access variable in the response of service which was declared in the same class in angular4?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {LoginService} from "../../services/login.service";
import {LoginUser} from "../../services/model";

@Component({
selector: 'login-component',
templateUrl: './login.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
private user: LoginUser = new LoginUser();
public flag : boolean = false;
constructor(private loginService: LoginService) {}

login(): void {
  this.flag = true;
  this.loginService.login(this.user).then(function (response) {
  console.log(this.flag);
  });
 }
}
```

I am not able to access or assign a value to flag variable in the response of login service call. However, I can access it in the login method where I updated its value to true.
I am facing the same problem in the login service as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular uses Typescript which by default has most of the ES6 features inside. Do not use `function(){}` if you want to pass in function as a callback argument.

Use [fat arrow notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) that gives you a lexical `this`:

```
login(): void {
    this.flag = true;
    this.loginService.login(this.user).then((response) => {
        console.log(this.flag);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @CozyAzure. It works. Unfortunately, because of low credit of my account, it won't be visible to the public profile. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Bind(this) might help you to solve you problem.

```
login(): void {   
    this.flag = true;   
    this.loginService.login(this.user).then((response)=>{ 
        console.log(this.flag);   
    });  
} }
```

Comment: We can't use ES6 and bind function together. We can resolve it using bind function as well. Though, by using below way.

    login(): void {
           this.flag = true;
           this.loginService.login(this.user).then(function(){
           console.log(this.flag);
        }.bind(this));
    }

Comment: Understood. No need to use bind(this). Angular uses typescript. @CozyAzure already answered it. Updated my answer.